Как в functions.php задать значение поля поста с помощью ACF?
Пользователь через форму на сайте отправляет отзыв.
Вот форма
<form id="review-form" class="review-form">
 <input type="text" id="name" name="name">
 <textarea id="comment" name="comment" required></textarea>
 <button type="submit" class="submit-btn">Отправить отзыв</button>
</form>

Вот functions.php
function handle_ajax_review_submission() {        
$review_id = wp_insert_post(array(
            'post_title'   => sanitize_text_field($_POST['name']),
            'post_content' => sanitize_textarea_field($_POST['comment']),
            'post_type'    => 'review',
            'post_status'  => 'pending',
        ));
         if ($review_id) {
    // Вот тут нужно в поля ACF с именами review_author_name и review_author_coment задать значения. Как это сделать?
            wp_send_json_success('Отзыв успешно отправлен');
         } else {
            wp_send_json_error('Не удалось сохранить отзыв');
         }

add_action('wp_ajax_submit_review', 'handle_ajax_review_submission');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_submit_review', 'handle_ajax_review_submission');

В комментариях в коде я показал где нужно дописать возможность задавать значения полям. Как это сделать с помощью ACF?

А форма-то где? И в ВП нет никаких отзывов и тех хуков, что ты написал.

Добавил форму))
